# mysql update datetime date with slashes

Tags: mysql, centos, mariadb

How to update DATETIME column in mysql

Tried using: (and many others)

I do not really care how the date is formatted in the database however need to be able to update the current row with the 01/01/2001 01:01 format

```
update contacts set replydate=STR_TO_DATE('1/9/2020 13:32', '%m/%d/%Y hh:mm') where id='3';
```

The date is not the current date, these are all different dates from a spread sheet, that all have the same formatting.

```
MariaDB [ddcontactsdb]> describe contacts;
+----------------+-----------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field          | Type            | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                       |
+----------------+-----------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| replydate      | datetime        | YES  |     | NULL              |                             | 
+----------------+-----------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
```

Comment: @forpas I need a command that will use '1/9/2020 13:32' I do not want to convert thousands of dates

Comment: @forpas Datetime does have a very specific format indicated in your single-quoted string. In addition, your comment does not take the input values into consideration.

Comment: @PanChristensen that comment should be deleted an I will delete it. My first thought when I read the question was that the OP wanted to update the column with a varchar date-like formatted value and that was the meaning of the *format*,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must use this format:

```
update contacts set replydate=STR_TO_DATE('1/9/2020 13:32', '%m/%d/%Y %H:%i') where id='3';
```

because `m` stands for month and `i` for minutes, also `H` for hour `00-23`.

Comment: MariaDB [ddcontactsdb]> select id,replydate from contacts where id=3;
+----+-----------+
| id | replydate |
+----+-----------+
|  3 | NULL      |
+----+-----------+